# Proving a bound inequality for all n

Tags: algorithms, induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\frac{n^n}{3^n} < n! < \frac{n^n}{2^n} $ for each $ n \geq 6 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193304/prove-that-fracnn3n-n-fracnn2n-forall-n-geq-6)

I want to prove $\dfrac{n^n}{3^n} \lt n! \lt \dfrac{n^n}{2^n}$ for all $n$ $\geq$ 6:

So we do the base case with $n$ = $6$ and it is really exciting.

Now for the induction hypothesis we assume the formula to be true. I started out by doing simple manipulations with $n+1$, however I get nowhere... (well I actually got close but my iff was actually just an if then...)

1. How can I get this off of the ground?
2. What pieces of information can I use?
3. Thanks!

Comment: I swear i saw this within the past few weeks, here on MSE. I thought it was a nice introduction to Stirling's.