# Please prove $n! > (n/3)^n$ is true, without using mathematical induction

Tags: limits

Please prove $n! > \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n$ is true, **without** using mathematical induction.
I've proved it using mathematical induction, but our teacher asked us to derive it using limits $n$ pre-calculus. I tried, but I'm stuck.

Comment: It would help a lot, if you could show exactly what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about Stirling approximation ?

Comment: @NitinJha Also related is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193304/prove-that-fracnn3n-n-fracnn2n-forall-n-geq-6).

Comment: It seems to me that any proof will use induction at least implicitly...

Comment: Please show us your proof by induction, I am really curious.

Answer (score 3):

Okay , now I have got it.
$$
\frac {n!}{(n/3)^n}
=
3^n \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)....}{n.n.n....}
=
3 \left( 3- \frac {3}{n} \right) \left( 3- \frac {6}{n} \right) \left( 3- \frac {9}{n} \right) ……
$$
If $n$ be a natural number, then the RHS is clearly more than 1 , hence the result.

## Edit

The general factor is,
$$
\left( 3- \frac {3k}{n} \right)
$$
It is obvious that whether $n→0$ or $n→∞$, the product tends to infinity, i.e. the function $\frac {n!}{(n/3)^n}$ grows monotonically. In case $n=1$, the result is trivial. Hence the result.

Comment: No, it is not clear that the RHS is greater than 1 when written in this way.